# WordPress & Docker dev/staging/live best workflow?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, devops

currently, I am working a lot with WordPress and for every project, my company wants different environments. So first of all we have our development environment which is running on our own server. Then there is the staging environment on the client's server and also the live(production) environment.
Also, there is the local environment in which every
participant developer is working on whatever features.

Since this is always a time-consuming hustle, I would love to use Docker to make things more straight forward.
So I set up my local environment with a docker-compose and create a MySql,WordPress and phpMyAdmin container.

With a shell script, I add a WordPress-theme and the Plugins from our private Gitlab repository as a submodule followed by the `docker-compose up -d`.
After all the containers are up and running I wait for a connection to the MySql-Database and then feed it with my backup.sql file.

That's all working fine so far...

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  wp-content: {}
  mysql-backup: {} 
networks:
  wp-back:
services:
  db:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql    
    container_name: mysql-cont
    volumes: ['mysql-backup:/root']
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wp-user
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp-pass
    ports:
      - 8889:3306
    networks:
      - wp-back
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma-cont
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: wp-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp-pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wp-back
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: wp-cont
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile-wordpress    
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 443:443     
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp-user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp-pass      
    volumes: ['./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content']
    networks:
      - wp-back
    restart: always
```

But regarding my needs with the 3 different environments, I am struggling with a setup where I can easily take everything that I created local and put it on the other 2 servers (dev & staging/live)
Because I always have the theme and the backup.sql in my docker volume, I somehow need to share that with other developers and the servers. I mean for the WordPress theme I could just work with pulling it from the project's private GitLab repository.
But what to do with the .sql file?
Where is the best place to put it?
Should I put Dockerfile, wp-content and backup.sql into one single repository for the project? It's getting pretty heavy then

Furthermore, let's say after a year I want to be able to easily set up the project in my local environment with the MySQL-database and WordPress uploads from the live environment. But I don't find a solution.

I appreciate any kind of brainstorming, ideas, help or links.

Cheers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108253/docker-wordpress-seperate-default-plugins-from-own-plugins and come discuss with us there :)